# Glitchy CSS3 skew animation (Chrome only)

Tags: css, animation, skew

Check this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KkgeL/.

How come it's so glitchy when animating it? I'm on Chrome v.33. Works perfectly fine in <strike>Safari and</strike> Firefox (Safari glitches the same way as Chrome [read below], but instead of the width it's the height).

edit: I can try to explain the glitch for those of you who don't see it. It animates all properties somewhat OK, but at the very end of the animation, the width of the 3 divs instantly changes by a handful of pixels which is very, very undesirable.

For those of you who use Chrome and doesn't see the glitch please comment with your Chrome version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet of what is this about, but I added a delay on the transition of `.logo > div` and the problem was solved but I don't know if you can retain this transition.
Try it and let me know

`-webkit-transition-delay: 1s;`.

Comment: I'm not looking for a delay on the transition. I want it to execute immediately. The glitch is that the width of the divs suddenly increases after the transition is done.